# R how to control decimal digits for zero on axis labels?

Tags: r, plot

The zero on axis labels sometimes show "0.0" or "0.00". how to adjust the zero without decimal digits "0". For example, I want to only adjust the "0.0" to "0" at y axis in following figure.[image]

```
plot(sin, -pi, 2*pi)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the [`axis`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/axis.html) function, and control the final display using the `at` and `labels` arguments.

```
plot(sin, -pi, 2*pi, yaxt = 'n') # make sure to specify yaxt = 'n'
axis(side = 2, at = c(-1, -.5, 0, .5, 1), labels = c('-1', '-0.5', '0', '0.5', '1'))
```

[image]